# Determine the coordinates of the point where the tangent meets the curve

Tags: derivatives

The line \begin{equation*}y=m(x-m)\end{equation*}  is tangent to the curve \begin{equation*}
(1-2x)y=1
\end{equation*}

How do you go about finding the coordinates of the point where they intersect? I differentiated the curve and got \begin{equation*}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2}{(1-2x)^2}\end{equation*}

How do I proceed on from this? Do I just equate the derivative to m and plot a graph using Wolfram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the line $y=m(x-m)$ touches the curve at the point $(a,b)$. Then the slope of the tangent at $(a,b)$ to the curve $(1-2x)y=1$ must be $m$ as the slope of the line $y=m(x-m)$ is $m$. So by your calculation $$\frac{2}{(1-2a)^2}=m.$$ But $(a,b)$ is a point on the line $y=m(x-m)$, whence $b=m(a-m)$. Now you have two unknowns and two equations. So find $(a,b)$.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

The line is $y=mx-m^2$.

Substitute this value of $y$ in the circle equation,

$$
(1-2x)(mx-m^2)=1
$$

or,

$$
mx-2mx^2-m^2+2m^2x = 1
$$

or,

$$
(2m)x^2 + (-2m^2-m)x + (m^2+1)
$$

Since this equation has only one root, $D=0$

**Can you proceed from here?**

Comment: Thanks, but I needed the method via derivative solving. Sorry.